# How to filter entire table with pagination?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a table with pagination and a search-box.

The current code below searches the entire table (i.e. data from page 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.) only while the user is on Page 1 of the table and returns correct results.

**Issue**

If I navigate to page 2, 3, 4 etc. I see the data but as soon as I start typing in the search box, no results are returned with my search term.  Not sure why but I suspect it is the **slice** in ngFor, could be very wrong though.  Any help is appreciated.

**Expected**

I want to be able to search the entire table from any page of the table, not just page 1.

**Customer HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-header border-0">
                <h3 class="mb-0">Customers</h3>
                <div class="search-bar-wrapper">
                    <form class="navbar-search form-inline mr-3 d-none d-md-flex ml-lg-auto">
                        <div class="form-group mb-0">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input id="searchInput" class="form-control" [formControl]="filter" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table align-items-center table-flush" id="customersTable">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Contact Email</th>
                            <th scope="col">Package</th>
                            <th scope="col">Subscription</th>
                            <th scope="col">Active</th>
                            <th scope="col">Customer Since</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let cust of customers$ | async | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
                            <td class="primaryColumn">
                                {{cust.name.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.email.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.package_name.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.subscription_name.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td [ngClass]="{
              'active' : cust.sub_status.BOOL == true,
              'inactive' : cust.sub_status.BOOL == false
           }">
                                {{cust.sub_status.BOOL}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.date_created.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <div ngbDropdown placement="bottom-right">
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" ngbDropdownToggle>
                                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="selectCustomer(cust);openForm(custUpdate)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><span class="menu-option">Edit</span></a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="selectCustomer(cust);openForm(custDelete)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i><span class="menu-option">Delete</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer py-4">
                <button id="create" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openForm(custCreate)">Create</button>
                <ngb-pagination [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" [collectionSize]="customers.length" [boundaryLinks]="true" [maxSize]="5"></ngb-pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Customer TS**

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {    
customers:any;
page= 1;
pageSize= 10;

customers$: Observable<any>;
filter = new FormControl('');

constructor(private dataService: DataService, private modalService: NgbModal, private 
customerService: CustomerService, private numberService: NumberService, 
private filterService: FilterService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,  private 
ngbDateParserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter, private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, pipe: DecimalPipe) {
  this.customers$ = this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(text => this.search(text, pipe))
  );
}

search(text: string, pipe: PipeTransform): any {
  return this.customers.filter(customer => {
    const term = text.toLowerCase();
    return customer.name.S.toLowerCase().includes(term)
 });
 }
```

}

**UPDATED SEARCH FUNCTION**

```
search(text: string, pipe: PipeTransform): any {
return this.customers.filter(customer => {
  if (customer.length < (this.page-1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize) {
    this.page++;
  }
  const term = text.toLowerCase();
  return customer.name.S.toLowerCase().includes(term)
});
```

}

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eaqjui

Comment: Here you go - there is a services getting data from the backend so cannot get it to display but I included the entire customer TS and HTML files.

Comment: looks like your code is correct, try to check the length of the filtered items in the search function and change the page if the length is less than `(page-1) * pageSize + pageSize`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Thanks for that.  I give that a shot.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Tried something as above but still no luck.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I think the function is wrong. let me correct the function

Comment: a wait. I think you have another issue too. let me update the function;

Comment: I have not found it yet but please do - thanks very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this one more time.

```
search(text: string, pipe: PipeTransform): any {
if(!text) {
  return this.customers;
}

  const filterdCustomers = this.customers.filter(customer => {
    const term = text.toLowerCase();
    return customer.name.S.toLowerCase().includes(term)
  });

  if (filterdCustomers.length < (this.page-1) * this.pageSize + 
  this.pageSize) {
    this.page = 1;
  }

  return filterdCustomers;

}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! You're the man - that works.  Thanks very much for that - I been scratching my all morning with this.

Comment: no problem, THank you too. But please check on your side one thing and let me know.

try to search something. and after remove your searched word. did you see any results?

Comment: I will try now - give me a sec.

Comment: No issues.  I put it a search term, it returns correct result from not considering which page I am on.  I then remove the search term completely and the table displays all data expected on that page.

Comment: ok, good. otherwise, i have updated the answer. I thought it will return an empty array.

Comment: Wonderful.  If I do come across any errors I will refer back to the updated answer.  Thanks again.